# Check for value to be in an array in $cond

Tags: mongodb

Im trying to project a value in my aggregation pipeline based on if any array in an array contaibns a specific value.

This is a simplified version of how the data looks:

```json
[
  {
    "permissions": [
      {
        "owners": [
          "1"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "permissions": [
      {
        "owners": [
          "2",
          "3"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And Ive tried to do the following (with "2" being the example value I am searching for):

```js
{
    "$project": {
      owner: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $in: [
              "2",
              "$permissions.owners"
            ]
          },
          then: true,
          else: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground Example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dcX66mCeGfJ)

But it always ends up being false. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `$permissions.owners` is a nested array. Check [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tdMa3Rd-oZN) example to look that.

So you have to `$unwind` the array. But, if there is only one array you can look for into first position in the array like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_M-fqR5kvnk)

But, assuming there could be many arrays, you can use this query.

- `$unwind` the array to get each value separated.
- `$set` the value into `owner` variable if exists the number 2.
- `$group` to get values again.

At this point, exists a variable called `owner` which is a boolean array. So the next step is similar to the query you have.

- `$set` again to know if exists `true` in any value, so, the variable will be true too.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$permissions"
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "owner": {
        "$in": [
          "2",
          "$permissions.owners"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "permissions": {
        "$push": "$permissions"
      },
      "owner": {
        "$push": "$owner"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "owner": {
        "$in": [
          true,
          "$owner"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JU2DJcjdZE8)